# Creating a custom device driver for a gamepad

Tags: windows, driver, gamepad

I have a few USB game controllers that are from "no-name" manufacturers that didn't provide drivers for the device. Currently they run under generic drivers in Windows, but the buttons don't map to the correct IDs and some buttons don't seem to work at all.  Under Android, I was able to fully map the controller with keylayout files, but it doesn't seem so simple in Windows.  Any help with creating a simple HID driver that maps a controller's inputs to native controller inputs the way it works in Android/Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Try [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/), it's a generic joystick driver that's already signed for use in Windows. If you write one yourself you'll have to boot into TESTSIGNING mode if you don't want to go through the signing process. There are some GUI tools out there that make vJoy configuration easier, check out [Universal Controller Remapper](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=12249).